# PHP Filter Validate is FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !==false is the negation of FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false correct for non-integer?

Tags: php, validation, filter

I have simple question i know i can safely use below code to check the if the variable is an integer or not using filter_var and FILTER_VALIDATE_INT function,

```
if(filter_var($variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false) {
    //$variable is not a integer for sure
}
```

However instead of writing an long else statement inside curly brackets, i like to check if the $variable is a integer sometimes rather than Not a integer, Can i use the below code (negation of the above code to check it?)

**Reason why i am asking is sometimes i know integers can be tricky with integer=0 is equal false and integer=1 is true in PHP**

```
if(filter_var($variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false ) {
   //if it's here, it passed the integer validation IS IT ? 
}
```

Any insight or sharing light into this issue?

Comment: `filter_var($variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false` will be `true` if and only if both type and value matches, therefore yes, it's safe

Comment: That's why you use `!==` rather than `!=`.